# New to Neo4j and cypher

Tags: php, neo4j

I am trying to learn neo4j with php, but I am having a hard time with the query statements. How would I go through my nodes that I make and assign an abv, ibu, srm, and brewery relationship using cypher.

```
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->addConnection('default','http','localhost',7474, true, 'neo4j', '123')->setDefaultTimeout(20)->build();

$version = $client->getNeo4jVersion();

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample data");

if(!$conn){
    mysqli_connect_error();
}
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'sample data');
if(!$db_selected){
  die();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM `beers` ";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(!$result){
    die(); 
}
$beer = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $temp = array();
    array_push($temp, $row['name']);
    array_push($temp, $row['abv']);
    array_push($temp, $row['ibu']);
    array_push($temp, $row['srm']);
    array_push($temp, $row['brewery_id']);
    array_push($beer,$temp);
}   
$i =0;
foreach ($beer as $name) {
    $temp = $name;
    if($i == 500){break;}else{$i++;}
    $q = "CREATE ( n {beer_name:"."\"".$name[0]."\","."ABV:".$name[1].","."IBU:".$name[2].","."SRM:".$name[3].","."brewey:".$name[4]."})";
    $client->sendCypherQuery($q);
    $result = $client->getRows();
}
```

Any help would be great I am stuck on what to do

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->addConnection('default','http','localhost',7474, true, 'neo4j', '123')->setDefaultTimeout(20)->build();

$version = $client->getNeo4jVersion();

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample data");

if(!$conn){
    mysqli_connect_error();
}
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'sample data');
if(!$db_selected){
  die();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM `beers` ";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(!$result){
    die(); 
}

$q =
  "CREATE (beer:Beer   {name: {name}})
   MERGE  (abv:Abv     {name: {abv}})
   MERGE  (ibu:Ibu     {name: {ibu}})
   MERGE  (srm:Srm     {name: {srm}})
   MERGE  (brw:Brewery {name: {brewery_id}})
   CREATE (beer)-[:ABV]->(abv),(beer)-[:IBU]->(ibu),(beer)-[:SRM]->(srm),(beer)-[:BREWERY]->(brw);";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
  $client->sendCypherQuery($q, $row);
}
```